# How would I write a SQL Server query that changes all date field in the database?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How would I write a SQL Server query that changes all fields in datetime columns in a database to **random** dates in the same, current year?

Comment: Look up RAND(). There are a lot of posts about how to get a random number between X and Y. I'd start with updating the month to a random number between 1-12. Then, depending on the month number, use rand for range 1-31 or 1-30 or 1-28 for feb. easy.

Answer (score 2):

This approach will convert the datetime ranges into a FLOAT.  Then we simply calculate a random number between these two values and convert that random value back into a datetime

**Example**

```
Declare @D1 float = cast(cast('2017-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime) as float) -- 42734
Declare @D2 float = cast(cast('2017-12-31 23:59:59' as datetime) as float) -- 43098.9999884259

Select Top 10
       RandomDate = cast(rand(cast( NewID() as varbinary ))*(@D2-@D1)+@D1 as datetime)
 From  master..spt_values A
```

**Returns**

```
RandomDate
2017-06-03 02:01:28.650
2017-06-12 01:05:54.107
2017-04-29 14:23:00.160
2017-10-13 14:37:51.290
2017-10-29 16:35:20.723
2017-06-30 20:54:03.197
2017-08-31 22:46:20.440
2017-02-11 23:42:24.323
2017-04-22 06:31:48.477
2017-12-01 18:05:49.177
```

> **EDIT - Dynamic**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Declare @D1 float = cast(cast(''2017-01-01 00:00:00'' as datetime) as float);
Declare @D2 float = cast(cast(''2017-12-31 23:59:59'' as datetime) as float);

'
 Select @SQL=@SQL+';Update '+quotename(Table_Schema)+'.'+quotename(Table_Name)+' Set '+quotename(Column_Name)+'=cast(rand(cast( NewID() as varbinary ))*(@D2-@D1)+@D1 as datetime)'+char(13)
  From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  Where Data_Type='datetime'
    and Table_Catalog = 'OnlineStore'

Print @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: If my database is named OnlineStore, what would I do to have this affect all tables in that database?

Comment: @ShreddedSaber You would have to go dynamic

Comment: What would I have to change in your example to make it be dynamic?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's not a crucial database. Thanks for your help with this, by the way.

Comment: @ShreddedSaber That's a relief.  I will be able to sleep tonight. 

Comment: Yeah, I'm not doing anything crazy to an important database haha! I've never seen the +quotename before. I'm getting errors with whatever I put in. What would you suggest I do with that? And what do you mean by Table_Schema? Dynamic SQL is just confusing.

Comment: Actually, I figured that part out. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ShreddedSaber quotename is a safety net if you have field names with spaces or odd characters.   Does no harm.   Table schema is usually dbo.   I did test on a test database and worked as expected.

Comment: @ShreddedSaber No worries

Comment: @JohnCappelletti your patience is admirable

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE t
SET    datetime_column = DATEADD(DAY, abs(checksum(newid())) % 364, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, datetime_column), 0))
FROM   yourtable t
```

the DATEADD() + DATEDIFF() pair will gives you 1st day of the year

abs(checksum(newid())) % 365 will return a random number between 0 and 364